# Create mysql view where

Tags: mysql, database, view

I have two table: `posts(id,title,text,type)` and `images(id, post_id, url)`.

I want to create view from all posts where `posts.type=1` and `posts.id = image.post_id`. It's really?

When I try:

```
CREATE VIEW image_posts AS
            SELECT * 
              FROM posts id
              INNER JOIN images post_id ON post_id = id;
```

I get:

```
Error in query (1052): Column 'id' in on clause is ambiguous
```

Comment: you didnt write us your query

Comment: `FROM posts id` - are you actually aware what this is …?

Comment: You're misunderstanding table aliases. By writing `posts id` you're setting up an alias on the `posts` table, saying that whenever you refer to `id` elsewhere in the query, you mean the `posts` table. Where two tables have the same field name, you need to qualify the table as well as the field name. A qualified field reference is something like this: `posts.id`. In your case, the qualified field name is `id.id` because of the alias that you set up.

Comment: Generally, if a SELECT doesn't work, then the view that's subsequently constructed from it isn't going to work either.

Comment: Please act on [mcve]. And tell us what you learned googling your error message without your particular table/column/constraint names. This is a faq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. To create a view, you need to write the query that you want the view to show the result for and then just add `CREATE VIEW <name> AS` in front of it.

```
CREATE VIEW mymegaview AS
SELECT posts.id, posts.title,posts.text, posts.type, image.id as image_id, 
    image.post_id, image.url
FROM `posts` LEFT JOIN `image` 
    ON  posts.id = image.post_id AND posts.type=1
```

Comment: Also, note, that in that view you will have multiple posts with same ids if one post have multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW image_posts AS
SELECT posts.id, posts.title, posts.text, posts.type, images.id as imgid,images.images
FROM posts posts INNER JOIN images images ON images.post_id = posts.id
AND posts.type=1;
```

Please refer CREATE VIEW Syntax at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html